# Send IRsend with mqtt to a Tasmota ir device

Tags: mqtt

I am writing a home automation program using Tasmota devices.
I have a YTF IR Bridge working well with most of my remotes.
for example with an Apple TV I can send

```
{"Protocol":"NEC","Bits":32,"Data":0x77E14005}
```

to select the menu.

I have come up with a problem with the Foxtel remote.
I have found codes for this on the net.
e.g.

```
Vol +
```

0000 0073 0000 0012 000F 000A 0006 000A 0006 0016 0006 000A 0006 0010 0006 0016 0006 0016 0006 000A 0006 000A 0006 000A 0006 0016 0006 0010 0006 0016 0006 000A 0006 0010 0006 000A 0006 000A 0006 0CA0

Vol –
0000 0073 0000 0012 000F 000A 0006 000A 0006 0016 0006 000A 0006 0010 0006 0016 0006 0016 0006 000A 0006 000A 0006 000A 0006 0016 0006 0010 0006 0016 0006 000A 0006 0010 0006 000A 0006 0010 0006 0C9B

I then converted these to ascii from hex and sent

```
cmnd/ir-bridge/IRSend  0,115,0,18,15,10,6,10,6,22,6,10,6,16,6,22,6,22,6,10,6,10,6,10,6,22,6,16,6,22,6,10,6,16,6,10,6,10,6,3232
```

with no result from the Foxtel box.
Could anyone give some clues on how to send this raw data.

Answer (score 1):

I had success with another group and found out how to decode this.
here is the Basic4Java code I use.

```
 Dim sb As StringBuilder
            sb.Initialize
            Dim Spllited() As String
            Spllited = Regex.Split(" ",payload)
            Dim N As Int
            N = Bit.ParseInt(Spllited(1), 16)
            Dim Frequency As Int = (1000000/(N * .241246)/1000)
            Dim pulse As Float = (1000/Frequency)
            sb.Append(Frequency).Append(",") ' Add frequency
            Dim OneTime As Int = Bit.ParseInt(Spllited(2), 16)
            Dim Repeat As Int = Bit.ParseInt(Spllited(3), 16)

            For z = 4 To Spllited.Length-1
                Dim Int_Number As Int
                Int_Number = Bit.ParseInt(Spllited(z), 16)
                Dim t As Int = Int_Number * pulse
                sb.Append(t)
                If z <> Spllited.Length-1 Then sb.Append(",")
            Next
            payload = sb.ToString
```

Tom